# Java program HugeInteger

Tags: java, runtime-error

I am writing a program that will add 2 arrays that are 40 elements long together. I have to keep the add() method as a HugeInteger (can’t change it to a integer) so when I try to return the sum of the 2 integers it gives me “HugeInteger@77e1ee5d”. Could someone let me know what this means and also tell me how I could fix it. 
Thank you

public class HugeInteger {

```
private int[] integer ;

public HugeInteger(int num[]){
    integer =new int [40];

    for(int x=1; x<=39; x++){           
        integer[x]= num[x];
    }

}

public void parse(String s){

    for(int i=0; i<=s.length(); i++){

        integer[i]=Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i,i+1));
    }

}

public HugeInteger add(HugeInteger a1){
    HugeInteger sum = new HugeInteger(integer);

    int cary=0;
      for (int i=39; i>=0; i--){
          sum.integer[i]=integer[i]+a1.integer[i]+cary;
          if(sum.integer[i]>=10){
              cary=1;
              sum.integer[i]-=10;
          }else{
              cary=0;
          }
      }
      return sum;   
}}
```

//This is my test program

```
public class HugeIntegerTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    int []num={1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

    HugeInteger hi= new HugeInteger(num);



    System.out.println("Addition: "+hi.add(hi));


}
```

}

Comment: You're seeing the default output of the `toString()` method, which includes a hexadecimal memory address.  To specify how the object should be represented as a string, you should override it's `toString()` method.

Comment: Pretty useless class indeed, `BigInteger` does all that and more much better. It's a good exercise though, toying around with adders and such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the output of the default `Object.toString()` method. You need to override `toString` and provide a better implementation yourself. An example:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(integer.length);
    for(int digit : integer) {
        builder.append(digit);
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Note that this implementation does not trim leading zeros, i.e. it will print "0000...000123" instead of just "123". This is left as an exercise for the reader, erm, programmer. ;-)

Another tip: in your constructor, your loop should start at `i=0`. Otherwise the most significant digit (`integer[0]`) will always be zero, for example your test program would give you a HugeInteger representing 0 instead of 10<sup>39</sup>.

Comment: I added the toString() method but it still returns "[I@927e4be"

Comment: Woops, I was appending the *array* to the builder instead of the `digit`. Try again with the updated code.

Comment: Thanks it works now. Do you know what the “HugeInteger@77e1ee5d” means?

Comment: it means "typeof(instance)@memory address"

Comment: It means `ClassName@hashcode` according to the Javadoc ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString() )

Answer (score 2):

You have to write your own version of the `toString()` for `HugeInteger` to make it display correctly.